# How to make a readonly field that can not be edited by user in a Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, readonly, disable

I'm trying to create my first own project in python django. What I'v done so far is a simple shop.
When I click this:

item_details.html

```
<a href="{% url 'buy_item' pk=item.pk %}" class="submit">Kup teraz</a>
```

I will be redirected

**urls.py**

```py
path('buy/<int:pk>', ItemCreate.as_view(), name='buy_item')
```

To this form:

**form.py**

```py
class BuyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
        'item',
        'delivery',
        'price',
        'buyer',)
```

With this view:

**views.py**

```py
class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Order
    fields = ['item', 'price', 'buyer', 'delivery']

    def get_initial(self):
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.initial.update({
            'buyer': self.request.user,
            'price': item.price,
            'item': item.pk,
        })
        return super(ItemCreate, self).get_initial()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True,
        upload_to='covers/%Y/%m/%D/')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Supplier(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Delivery(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_of_delivery = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery = models.ForeignKey(Delivery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Because the initial data shouldn't be edited by user, I'd like to make them readonly.

What I've tried so far is:

```
class BuyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(BuyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['buyer'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True    

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
        'item',
        'delivery',
        'price',
        'buyer',)
```

No errors in my console but also there's no results.

My order_form.html looks that:

```
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div align="center">
    <h1>Buy item</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Buy</button>
    </form>
</div>
<
{% endblock %}
```

What should I do to make "buyer", "price" and the "item" readonly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All other answers are great and correct, but that didn't solve the problem when I created your example.

Actual problem is that your view never use your form in a first place - that's why overriding attributes did nothing!

More about class-based views with custom forms from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Item
from .forms import BuyForm

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = BuyForm
    template_name = 'order_form.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def get_initial(self):
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.initial.update({
            'buyer': self.request.user.id,
            'price': item.price,
            'item': item.pk,
        })
        return super(ItemCreate, self).get_initial()
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Order


class BuyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['buyer'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'item',
            'delivery',
            'price',
            'buyer',)
```

Comment: Fields are disabled but it shows "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." and I can not submit my order.

Comment: @Eliro You need to provide `user.id` in initials instead of just `user`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class BuyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(BuyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['buyer'].required = False
       self.fields['buyer'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = "disabled" 

       ...

    def clean_buyer(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance:
            return instance.buyer
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data.get('buyer', None)
```

but the filed with disabled attr will post `blank` data. That why we override the `clean` method to set the field's value to be what was originally in the instance.

Comment: Despite using the clean function, it post blank data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a formfield's `disabled` attribute:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Answer (score -4):

Another approach is to make them hidden fields.  Add this to the Meta...

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'buyer': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'price': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'item': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```

Comment: No results and no errors. I still can edit initial data. By the way - I'd like to make a READonly fields. How can I READ hidden input?